# Convert indentation in entire folder

Tags: bash, directory, indentation, subdirectory

I'm working in a large project with ~35,500 files and I want o know if I cold convert the indentation of the entire project. I know I can do

```
unexpand -t 4 <file>
```

but I can't run it for every single file.

I was thinking about some way of doing it with `tree`, which I know I can manipulate to print every file name with complete path... or does someone know a shell program that can iterate over all files in folder and subfolders so I could use `unexpand`?

Comment: Please include what you have attempted so far to write such shell program

Comment: @Andreas I did it with VS Code's Find and Replace. But I think it's possible with `find` and unexpand (if I could change the "print to stdout" behavior). Thx anyway!

Comment: @VitorMattos : Do it in two steps: First write a small shell script which is just doing the `unexpand` for one file; it will need a temporary file, since `unexpand` writes to stdout. Then use `find` with this script. This has also the advantage that you can easily add additional checking if you need to (such as exempting binary files from being unexpanded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `unexpand` does not have an overwrite option, please try:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir="."
while read -r -d "" file; do
    tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/tempfile.XXXXXX)
    unexpand -t 4 "$file" > "$tmpfile"
    cp --preserve=all --attributes-only -- "$file" "$tmpfile"  # will work with GNU cp only
    mv -f -- "$tmpfile" "$file"
done < <(find "$dir" -type f -print0)
```

The line starts with `cp` just copies the attributes of the original one. You can comment-out the line if it does not work.
Please make sure to back up the original files before execution.